# ffplay streaming webcam h264 reconnect

Tags: ffmpeg

I am watching webcam streams on Linux using ffplay over Wi-Fi

Because Wi-Fi not so good, or when the webcam is restarted, ffplay streaming stops but ffplay does not discover this

How can I make ffplay reconnect if the A-V counter stops for 1 second?
is there an option?

Playing an rtsp h-264 stream like:
ffplay rtsp://1.2.3.4:5554

Answer (score -1):

Try using various methods.

NoBuffer:
ffplay -fflags nobuffer -rtsp_transport rtsp://1.2.3.4:5554

UDP:
ffplay -rtsp_transport udp rtsp://1.2.3.4:5554

Low_Delay:
ffplay -fflags nobuffer -flags low_delay rtsp://1.2.3.4:5554

FrameDrop:
ffplay -framedrop rtsp://1.2.3.4:5554

Strict:
ffplay -strict experimental rtsp://1.2.3.4:5554

Combo:
ffplay -fflags nobuffer -flags low_delay -framedrop -strict experimental -rtsp_transport udp rtsp://1.2.3.4:5554

Also, check and see if your webcam offers a SubStream versus MainStream